# Network load on reading file in batch? StreamReader is in memory or just a pointer to file?

Tags: c#

I am using following code to read file content in BATCH.
I am worried about Network load, Because I dont know StreamReader reads from file or memory for every batch?

```
sr =  File.OpenText(path); // does it keep entore content in memory?
```

### Full code here

```
public class CustomFileReader :IEnumerable<List<string>>,IDisposable
{
    StreamReader sr;
    int _batchSize = 1;

    public CustomFileReader(string path, int batchSize)
    {
        if (batchSize > 0)
        {
            _batchSize = batchSize;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Batch size should be greather than Zero", "batchSize");
        }
        sr =  File.OpenText(path);// sr is in memory or just a pointer to file?
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (sr != null)
        {
            sr.Close();
        }
    }



    public IEnumerator<List<string>> GetEnumerator()
    {

        string input = string.Empty;

        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            int i = 0;
            List<string> batch = new List<string>();

            while (i < _batchSize && !string.IsNullOrEmpty((input = sr.ReadLine())))
            {
                batch.Add(input);
                i++;
            }

            if (batch.Count != 0)
            {
                yield return batch;
            }
        }
        Dispose();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Shall I use c# object to store file contents?

Answer (score 0):

`File.OpenText` does not yet read the contents of the file. Also, creating a `StreamReader` does not yet read the file.

The file is read only if you call one of the `Read...` functions on the `StreamReader` and even then, the file is not yet read in total, but only so far as you want. If you want to read 512 bytes, 512 bytes are read and the stream's internal position is advanced by 512 bytes. If you want to read a line of text, the line is read and the position is advanced to the next line.

What *may* happen is that the OS recognizes your intent to read a file. In that case is might pre-read the file so your stream can access it faster. But that's not in the scope of your application anyway.